# Implement game idea into andengine(Rango stretchable tongue)

Tags: android, 2d, andengine

I hope you guys would share your experiences and ideas with me

anyway, i want to make a chameleon character with stretchable tongue like the real one do.
i've tried to look at the samples and tutors, for now i try to use revolute joint to make the tongue.
however, it requires physics environment that probably unnecessary. Also, with revolute joint i'm afraid the tongue wouldn't be able to animate perfectly(like blocks segmentation).

maybe for better illustration u guys can take a look at angry birds catapult.
the rubber seems like cartoon while it's stretching, right? i'm wondering if i can make the same thing

*if some of u guys can achieve this wth other engine, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

I've spent lots of days trying to create some nice-looking ropes with AndEngine, and I can say that it's nearly impossible. Box2D itself is badly ported and it has many glitches with calculations, resulting in poor looking joints. For example, `WeldJoint` isn't really a weld joint, since it doesn't hold two bodies strong enough and you can always see some space between them. With `RevoluteJoint` problem is the same: ropes don't really look like ropes, and in most cases they behave really strange.. I've found it absolutely not possible to create ropes like in Cut the Rope. Other engines I've tried are also pretty glitchy, and btw AndEngine seems the best one.. In my opinion, you won't get much of joints in AndEngine. You can use them in some really simple situations, cause it's a big question how will joints behave on different devices.

Hope we can see some really good physics engines in future.

Comment: well seems like real problem, but actually i think i gonna use animated sprite to simulate it instead by using physics :p